# Scroll Container can't be added

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying feathers for the first time and keep getting this error when I try to add a ScrollContainer to the stage

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 13, Column 21   1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type feathers.controls:ScrollContainer to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

this is the code I'm using

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import feathers.controls.ScrollContainer;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import feathers.layout.HorizontalLayout;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import feathers.controls.Button;

var container:ScrollContainer = new ScrollContainer();
 var layout :HorizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
 layout.gap = 20;
 layout.padding = 20;
 container.layout = layout;
 this.addChild( container );

 var yesButton :Button = new Button();
 yesButton.label = "Yes";
 container.addChild( yesButton );

 var noButton:Button = new Button();
 noButton.label = "No";
 container.addChild( noButton );
```

is there any thing that I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

Feathers runs on Starling only, so you can add Feathers controls only to Starling display objects, like starling.display.Sprite. You're trying to add a Feathers control to a Flash display object and those two can't be mixed.

You should configure Starling in your project. You can start from here http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/flash-pro , http://gamua.com/starling/first-steps/, http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html

If you're keen on using Starling and Feathers, then you would be better off switching to a different IDE like Flash Develop. It's quite painful working with Starling in Flash Pro CS.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I have configured starling in my project and will be very grateful if you would give me an example on how to add feathers to Starling display objects. I have tried executing the code used in the examples from starling but still same error with each feathers component I use.